# Batch Entry of NEW Pledges?

Tags: drupal, pledges

We have a unique organization (large homeschool coop) that has various oddball requirements for membership types, durations, payments, etc.

I think I'm going to be using Pledges to solve some of our woes, and am wondering if it is possible to do a batch entry of NEW pledges. I see that you can do a batch entry of pledge payments, but can I do something like this?

Search for memberships with a certain status.

Take search results and create a new pledge for those people and set the details like Campaign associated with it, total pledge amount, pledge status?, and monthly payment plan.

Thanks!

Drupal 7.41
CiviCRM 4.6.10

Answer (score 2):

If you export your search results to a CSV, you can then import them as pledges with the [API csv Import GUI extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui).  Setting up the columns correctly for the import will presumably take a little trial and error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Will take a look at that extension!